# Vaadin table column formatting for Timestamp class

Tags: vaadin

I am using a table with sql container.  The container's data source is a free form query.  One of the field is an invoice date and in the sql server, the field is a small date time.  I've overriden the formatPropertyValue function and when i debugged it "property.getType()" was returning "Timestamp".  so this is what i've done within the function.

```
if (property.getType() == Timestamp.class) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        if (property.getValue() == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            System.out.println(df.format( (Date) property.getValue()));
            return df.format( (Date) property.getValue());

        }
    }
```

When I run the application, i get the "com.vaadin.ui.table$cacheupdateexception" error.

I got around by changing the sql statement like "query = "SELECT convert(varchar(10), INVOICE_DATE, 110) as  INVOICE_DATE,..." but i was wondering if there was a proper way to format a Timestamp field.

Thanks,

Thomas Kim.

Comment: When you see a com.vaadin.ui.table$cacheupdateexception error thrown in the table component, then look at the exception informaion you receive, there is additional information which usually leads to the real problem. (Null values, invalid classes etc.)

Comment: I am hoping that it doesn't happen again :) but if it does, i will take a more closer look.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

i've found out that my code has a bug.  it should be

```
return df.format( (Timestamp) property.getValue());
```

instead of

```
return df.format( (Date) property.getValue());
```

It's working now.